# For horizontal ng-repeat, how to remove spaces between elements and sync it up with a second ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to print out an ng-repeat without all the space in between the elements. I want it to be about half as much as there is right now.

I also need it to be in sync with another ng-repeat below it.

How do I get this to happen? Here it is right now:

```js
$scope.profileCompare = {

  You: {
    questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, false, false],
    percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
    questionImportance: "Unimportant"
  },
  Pizza: {
    questionAnswer: [true, false, false, false, false, false],
    percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
    questionImportance: "Important"
  },
  Greenie: {
    questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, true, false],
    percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
    questionImportance: "Very Important"
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in profileCompare">
    <p>{{value.questionImportance}}</p>
    <ul class="comparison-list">
      <li ng-repeat="answer in value.questionAnswer track by $index" style="position:relative; display:block; float:right" class="fa-li fa" ng-class="{green:answer, red:!answer, 'fa-check-square':answer, 'fa-square':!answer}">
      </li>
      <br>
      <li ng-repeat="percent in value.percent track by $index" style="position:relative; float:right">
        {{percent}}
      </li>
      <br>
      <br>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to shrink the space between the elements on both of them, and get the first ng-repeat of `answer in value.questionAnswer` to sync up to be right above the second one `percent in value.percent`. As it is now, it's offset about one element to the left.

Comment: this is definitely more of a CSS/HTML question than angular, but I think this is one of the few cases where using tables makes sense, similar to the code that I posted in answer to your question yesterday.

Comment: The snippet you provided is not working.

Comment: Better show the resulting html and show it together with the css. This is a layout issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem to get a proper styling is that `answer` and `percent` array have different length. It would be easier if you could make them same size. (e.g. both 5 items).

Anyway, if you need them like they are you could do it with a table (as proposed in the comments). To make them look nicer you can add a `colspan=2` to a percent cell. Required because of the different length.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/ktLye1ps/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.profileCompare = {

        You: {
            questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, false, false],
            percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
            questionImportance: "Unimportant"
        },
        Pizza: {
            questionAnswer: [true, false, false, false, false, false],
            percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
            questionImportance: "Important"
        },
        Greenie: {
            questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, true, false],
            percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
            questionImportance: "Very Important"
        }
    }
});
```

```css
td {
    text-align: center;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, profile) in profileCompare">
        <p>{{profile.questionImportance}}</p>
        {{key}}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="answer in profile.questionAnswer track by $index"><i class="fa" ng-class="{green:answer, red:!answer, 'fa-check-square':answer, 'fa-square':!answer}"></i></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="percent in profile.percent track by $index" colspan="{{$index == 0? 2: ''}}">
                    {{percent}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it evidently, but I did add a '0%' to the one, and the problem is still the same. They are both float: right, and the one with the answers is not putting anything on the furthest right part.

Comment: Should it look like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/ktLye1ps/2/). I've added a wrapper around the `ul` list that's floated to the right and some padding + fixed width to the `li` to make is look like with the table.

Comment: That's exactly the behavior I want. But for some reason when I copied that code into my html, it doesn't appear

Comment: Ah nevermind, I had modified my object to try it another way.

Comment: Great, this is perfect. One more problem, though - the width of the elements is too wide, and its flowing over into the next line. I have to fix this next